# Oracle : Select only particular value from a row

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle12c

I have a like below

data :

```
1234=A||1456=B||1789=C
1245=||1234=V
1234,1133
1456=||1234=1,234||1234
```

so i wanted to remove all the value after = and before | except for 1234.

expected data :

```
1234=A||1456=||1789=
1245=||1234=V
1234,1133
1456=||1234=1,234||1234
```

Comment: With `after = and |` you mean `after = and *before* |  *or end of the line*`?

Comment: Ya exactly after = and before |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '(^|\|)((1234=.*?)|(\d+=).*?)(\||$)',
         '\1\3\4\5'
       ) AS value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '1234=A||1456=B||1789=C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1245=||1234=V' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234,1133' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1456=||1234=1,234||1234' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 1234=A||1456=||1789= |
> | 1245=||1234=V |
> | 1234,1133 |
> | 1456=||1234=1,234||1234 |

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e85fd4/2)*

Comment: Nice answer +1.  Note that if Oracle's regex engine supported negative lookaheads (and word boundaries) then your life would have been much easier.